# Aspose.cell and Aspose.pdf to output data based on template from json input

Tags: templates, xlsx, aspose

we want data place holders in excel. We have input data in json format.
How can we use aspose.cell to map the data to placeholder at runtime in the provided xlsx and generate excel output?

is there way to define template similarly for pdf which can load data from json?

The transformation routine using aspose translates json to xls format and pdf format in few lines of code. i.e.

1. create a workbook
2. mapping data to workbook

is there a sample i can refer for aspose place holder in xlsx and pdf?

Answer (score 0):

We are afraid, you cannot put data from JSON to Aspose.Cells Workbook directly. You will have to create a Data Table or Array List from JSON first and then you can use the Smart Marker features for your needs. You will specify some tags in your Excel file, it will be called Template Excel file or Designer Excel file. Then you will import data into it from various data sources e.g. list or data tables etc.

Besides that, you can import data into your worksheet or export data from your worksheet using Aspose.Cells APIs.

Lastly you can save your Workbook or Excel file to Pdf formats.

Please refer to these documentation from online Aspose.Cells documentation for your more help and sample codes.

> - Smart Markers > Using Smart Markers
> - Smart Markers > Auto Populate Smart Marker Data to Other Worksheets if Data is too Large
> - Data > Import Data into Worksheet
> - Data > Export Data from Worksheet
> - Loading, Saving, Converting and Managing > Convert Excel Workbook to PDF

In case you find any difficulty in searching the articles from Aspose documentation, please feel free to let us know, we will provide you direct links.

**Update 1**

---

Please see the following screenshot, it shows the following Excel files used inside the following **Java and C# Code**.

- TemplateDesigner.xlsx
- outputSmartMarker.xlsx

Please read the annotations on the screenshot that explain **what are the Smart Markers(tags) and how they are processed.**

[image: Explain Aspose.Cells Smart Marker Feature with Java]

**Java**

```
//Person class having Country, Name, Age and Address Properties
public class Person
{
    String m_country;
    String m_name;
    int m_age;
    String m_address;

    public Person(String country, String name, int age, String address)
    {
        this.m_country = country;
        this.m_name = name;
        this.m_age = age;
        this.m_address = address;
    }

    public String getCountry()
    {
        return this.m_country;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.m_name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return this.m_age;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return this.m_address;
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------

public void Run() throws Exception
{
    //List of the persons
    ArrayList<Person> lstPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    //China
    lstPersons.add(new Person("China", "Simon1", 33, "AB Town1"));
    lstPersons.add(new Person("China", "Simon2", 34, "AB Town2"));
    lstPersons.add(new Person("China", "Simon3", 35, "AB Town3"));
    lstPersons.add(new Person("China", "Simon4", 36, "AB Town4"));

    //England
    lstPersons.add(new Person("England", "John1", 28, "CH Town1"));
    lstPersons.add(new Person("England", "John2", 27, "CH Town2"));
    lstPersons.add(new Person("England", "John3", 26, "CH Town3"));

    //USA
    lstPersons.add(new Person("USA", "James1", 19, "JF Town1"));
    lstPersons.add(new Person("USA", "James2", 15, "JF Town2"));

    //Iran
    lstPersons.add(new Person("Iran", "Jack1", 24, "SK Town1"));
    lstPersons.add(new Person("Iran", "Jack2", 25, "SK Town2"));
    lstPersons.add(new Person("Iran", "Jack3", 26, "SK Town3"));

    //Load the template Excel file containing Smart Markers
    Workbook wb = new Workbook(dirPath + "TemplateDesigner.xlsx");

    //Create workbook designer
    WorkbookDesigner wd = new WorkbookDesigner(wb);

    //Set the data source
    wd.setDataSource("Person", lstPersons);

    //Process the smart marker
    wd.process();

    //Save the output Excel file
    wb.save(dirPath + "outputSmartMarker.xlsx");
}
```

**C#**

```
//Person class having Country, Name, Age and Address Properties
class Person
{
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}

//---------------------------------------------

static void Run()
{
    //List of the persons
    List<Person> lst = new List<Person>();

    //China
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "China", Name = "Simon1", Age = 33, Address = "AB Town1" });
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "China", Name = "Simon2", Age = 34, Address = "AB Town2" });
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "China", Name = "Simon3", Age = 35, Address = "AB Town3" });
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "China", Name = "Simon4", Age = 36, Address = "AB Town4" });

    //England
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "England", Name = "John1", Age = 28, Address = "CH Town1" });
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "England", Name = "John2", Age = 27, Address = "CH Town2" });
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "England", Name = "John3", Age = 26, Address = "CH Town3" });

    //USA
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "USA", Name = "James1", Age = 19, Address = "JF Town1" });
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "USA", Name = "James2", Age = 18, Address = "JF Town2" });

    //Iran
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "Iran", Name = "Jack1", Age = 24, Address = "SK Town1" });
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "Iran", Name = "Jack2", Age = 25, Address = "SK Town2" });
    lst.Add(new Person() { Country = "Iran", Name = "Jack3", Age = 26, Address = "SK Town3" });

    //Load the template Excel file containing Smart Markers
    Workbook wb = new Workbook("TemplateDesigner.xlsx");

    //Create workbook designer
    WorkbookDesigner wd = new WorkbookDesigner(wb);

    //Set the data source
    wd.SetDataSource("Person", lst);

    //Process the smart marker
    wd.Process();

    //Save the output Excel file
    wb.Save("outputSmartMarker.xlsx");

}
```

**Update 2**

---

The following smart marker explains how to use repeat dynamic formula

```
&=&=Sum(E{r}:F{r})
```

The entire smart markers are as follows

```
Country Age1    Age2    Repeat Dynamic Formula
&=Person.Country(group:merge,skip:2)    &=Person.Age    &=Person.Age    &=&=Sum(E{r}:F{r})
```

Please see the following screenshot. It shows the template Excel file containing smart markers and output Excel file and the output Excel when show formulas have been clicked.

[image: Aspose.Cells Placeholders Smart Markers - Repeat Dynamic Formula]

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: Can you please provide reference of code of creating template with place holders using smart markers

Comment: Please let us know if you are using Java or C# (.NET Framework). We will then look into it and provide you a sample code in Java or C# as per your requirement. Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: Hi it is for java.

Comment: @anjana, please check the Update-1 in the reply. It explains the smart marker feature of Aspose.Cells, its markers or tags and how they are processed. Please see the screenshot and its annotations. I have provided the code in Java as well as in C# for your help and other users. Thank you and regards.

Comment: Thanks you for followup can same template be used for generating pdf output or do we have another template type with smart marker tags for pdf

Comment: i want to try the aspose-cell to evaluate the excel formualae with smartmarker i have downloaded the aspose-cell trial what is the step to intrgrated in my java app

Comment: If you want to save to pdf, then you will use this line, only .xlsx is changed to .pdf. ---- wb.save(dirPath + "outputSmartMarker.pdf"); -- and now you will get output in pdf format.

Comment: Yes, you can use Excel formulas in Smart Marker features. Before moving further, please experiment the code I provided. For formulae, you will have to use these Smart Markers (tags) ---- &==DynamicFormula ---- &=&=RepeatDynamicFormula ---- For code examples, please visit this Java article: https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsjava/Using+Smart+Markers ---- similarly, you can also visit this C#/.NET article: https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Using+Smart+Markers --- Regards.

Comment: Hi , I have done POC with evaluation version using above smart marker tags. Couple of question.I put the dynamic forumale to sum a column however the sum only return the value of first row it does not accumulates the values of other rows. This is what is specified in template &=&=SUM(L11,L11) In my generated output i  have dynamic data till L18. It does not get added.

Comment: Also the formats of number columns does not appear in final output

Comment: You will have to set the number format of the cell that contains smart marker either manually using Microsoft Excel or programmatically using Cell.setStyle() method. For dynamic formulas, please spare us some time, we will look into it and update you tomorrow hopefully.

Comment: @anjana, I have explained how to employ smart markers repeat dynamic formulas. Please check the Update-2 for your reference. Thanks and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Aspose.PDF API, you can add text to any placeholder in a PDF document once you convert JSON data to Data Table or Array List. You can use below code snippet to add text on a PDF page.

```
// Open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document(dataDir + "input.pdf");

// Get particular page
Page pdfPage = (Page)pdfDocument.Pages[1];

// Create text fragment
TextFragment textFragment = new TextFragment("main text");
textFragment.Position = new Position(100, 600);

// Set text properties
textFragment.TextState.FontSize = 12;
textFragment.TextState.Font = FontRepository.FindFont("TimesNewRoman");
textFragment.TextState.BackgroundColor = Aspose.Pdf.Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
textFragment.TextState.ForegroundColor = Aspose.Pdf.Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

// Create TextBuilder object
TextBuilder textBuilder = new TextBuilder(pdfPage);

// Append the text fragment to the PDF page
textBuilder.AppendText(textFragment);

dataDir = dataDir + "AddText_out.pdf";

// Save resulting PDF document.
pdfDocument.Save(dataDir);
```

For further information on working with text, you may visit [Add text to a PDF file](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Add+Text+to+a+PDF+file).

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: if have one xls template can it be converted to PDF using Aspose. PDF

Comment: You can convert an XLS file to a PDF file with Aspose.Cells for .NET. Please try using below code snippet in your environment and then share your kind feedback with us.

    // Open an Excel file
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook(dataDir + "Book1.xls");


    // Save the document in PDF format
    workbook.Save(dataDir + "output.pdf", SaveFormat.Pdf);

For further details about this conversion, you may visit this documentation article: https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Convert+Excel+Workbook+to+PDF#ConvertExcelWorkbooktoPDF-ConvertingExcelWorkbooktoPDF